# Populate dropdown from MySQL Database Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a Flask backend with MySQL and need to pull values from a table to display in a dropdown.

I have a table with single values like Banana, Apple, Orange, etc.

Inside my html code, the option shows up if a user selects another dropdown (which is hard-coded) so the code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
        $("#inputType").change(function() {
            var myform = "<div id=\"newForm\">"
            +"<label for=\"inputFruit\">Fruit:</label>"
            +"<select class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputFruit\" required>"
            +"<option></option>"
            +"</select>"
            if ($("#inputType").val() == "fruits") {
                $(myform).insertBefore("#btnSignUp");
            } else {
                $("#newForm").remove();
            }
```

Inside my flask app:

```
@app.route('/getFruits') # gets my fruits as a list and returns
```

Where do I add code so that the values I get from /getFruits is put into the option in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the context data (fruits list) into javascript code of your template, use JSON will meet your requirement:

**Your View:**

```
import json

@app.route('/getFruits')
def my_view():
    data = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Watermalon'] # you can get list from your DB instead
    return render_template('yourtemplate.html', data=json.dumps(data))
```

**Your Template:**

```
$(function() {
        $("#inputType").change(function() {
            var myform = "<div id=\"newForm\">"
            +"<label for=\"inputFruit\">Fruit:</label>"
            +"<select class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputFruit\" required>"
            {% for item in data %}
            +"<option>{{ item|safe }}</option>"
            {% endfor %}
            +"</select>"
            if ($("#inputType").val() == "fruits") {
                $(myform).insertBefore("#btnSignUp");
            } else {
                $("#newForm").remove();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, what if I have two dropdowns? If I had a data1 and data2 inside of my_view?

Comment: @user1883614 It will be similar, just add one more variable, and pass the variable in the `render_template('yourtemplate.html', data1=json.dumps(data1), data2=json.dumps(data2))`, after that in your template, you can for loop data1 and data2 separately, and assign the variables into two dropdown Correspondingly.

Comment: Basically, you can render a template with the given context (the variables that should be available in the context of the template), please refer to [Template Rendering](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/). You can pass multiple variables to template, just make sure your variable can be "understood" by javascript.

Comment: @Tiny.D, you should not be using json with Flask, instead use jsonify which is provided by Flask itself, more secure.